# How to update time elapsed

Tags: java, timer

I'm developing a program which will count the time until the button is clicked
I'm having trouble with using Timer. I wanted to have something like
00:00:00 -> 00:00:01 -> 00:00:02 ... etc
my problem is that

it is stuck in 00:00:01

here's my code

```
Timer timer=new Timer(1000,null);


JLabel time=new JLabel("00:00:00");
timer.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
         DecimalFormat df=new DecimalFormat("00");
         int h=0;
         int m=0;
         int s=0;
         s++;
         if(s==60)
         {
             m++;
             if(m==60)
             {
                  h++;
             }
         }
         time.setText(df.format(h)+":"+df.format(m)+":"+df.format(s));
         revalidate();
         repaint();
      }
   });
   timer.start();
```

Comment: And what's the problem?

Comment: Why dont you use a [DateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html) instead doing so many things ?

Comment: @ItachiUchiha Because a `DateFormat` wouldn't be able to display over 24 hours (30:15:10) for example

Comment: Does he wants that ? I guess the OP will be calculating till 23:59:59 only :P

Comment: @MadProgrammer sorry I forgot to state the problem :D I updated the post

my problems is it only increments 1 time and now it's stucked to 00:00:01

Comment: Well, to start with if `s` >= `60`, you're not resetting `s` to `0`

Comment: well actually I didn't think of the time reaching hours ((: cause I'm going to use this on a Kitchen Display System which will more likely take only minutes I guess?

Comment: Ok @MadProgrammer I tried it in my code and it still stuck in 00:00:01

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you, you should first store the startTime -

```
final long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

Then use it to calculate your time fields in `actionPerformed()`,

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("00");
long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
long diff = endTime - startTime;
int h = (int) (diff) / (60*60*1000);
diff -= h * (60*60*1000);
int m = (int) (endTime-startTime) / (60*1000);
diff -= m * (60 * 1000);
int s = (int) (diff / 1000);

time.setText(df.format(h) + ":" + df.format(m)
    + ":" + df.format(s));
revalidate();
repaint();
```

**Edit**

Based on your new requirements,

Replace

```
final long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

with

```
final Calendar startTime = Calendar.getInstance();
```

and then

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("00");
long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
long diff = endTime - startTime.getTimeInMillis();
int h = (int) (diff) / (60 * 60 * 1000);
diff -= h * (60 * 60 * 1000);
int m = (int) (endTime - startTime.getTimeInMillis()) / (60 * 1000);
diff -= m * (60 * 1000);
int s = (int) (diff / 1000);
```

Comment: @askManiac Oops. Fixed.

Comment: thank you very much :D it works but I have another problem...
because I'm doing a kitchen display system and orders may come every moment what happens is every time the kitchen receives the order the timer restarts

Comment: @askManiac Next time post all your requirements with the question. Now you'll need to track startTime differently. I'd probably change it to a Calendar, because you it can stay final and you can change the time with `setTime(new Date());` when it needs to reset.

Comment: sorry I didn't expect that, that would happen :D

Comment: what do you mean change startTime with Calendar?

Comment: @askManiac `final Calendar startTime = Calendar.getInstance();`

Comment: then what would happen to long diff and int m? what will I change them?

Comment: @askManiac You'll need to call [`getTimeInMillis()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getTimeInMillis%28%29) from Calendar in your ActionListener.

Comment: huh?! ahaha Sorry I haven't tackled any of this stuff yet.. can you help me

Comment: Try asking another question, and post all of your requirements.

Comment: can't it says I can only post once every 90mnts

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57888/discussion-between-askmaniac-and-elliott-frisch).

Answer (score 2):

You've declared your variables as local variables within the context of the `ActionListener`...

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
     DecimalFormat df=new DecimalFormat("00");
     int h=0;
     int m=0;
     int s=0;
```

This means that each time `actionPerformed` the variables are reset to `0`...

Try making them instance variables instead...

You're also not resetting the variables when they pass their limits, for example...

```
s++;
if (s >= 60) {
    s = 0;
    m++;
    if (m >= 60) {
        h++;
        m = 0;
    }
}
```

As an alternative, you could maintain a single counter, which acts as the number of seconds that have passed and use some module mathematics to calculate the time parts

```
private int count = 0;

//...

Timer timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        count++;

        int hours = count / (60 * 60);
        float remainder = count % (60 * 60);
        float mins = remainder / (60);
        remainder = remainder % (60);
        float seconds = remainder;

        DecimalFormat df=new DecimalFormat("00");
        time.setText(df.format(hours) + ":" + df.format(mins) + ":" + df.format(seconds));

    }
});
timer.start();
```

This makes it a little simpler in the fact that you are managing a single value and then deciding how best to format it, rather then managing three states...IMHO

Comment: what's count? just a simple int?